# Running my app on static ip address

Tags: tomcat, ip, tomcat7

I have a sample web application, which runs on 192.168.x.xxx:8080(Tomcat 7).I want to run this app to run on my static IP address.
I have googled and found a site which tells my Static IP address [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/show_my_ip_address.php) .
Now how do i run my application which is deployed in 192.168.X.XXX and port 8080, using static ip address ? 
[Link](http://www.nirsoft.net/show_my_ip_address.php) provides my ip and and running port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure your router in order to forward `TCP 8080 port` packets to the internal address which `Tomcat` is bound to.

How to do this depends on your router. The general way is to search `Port Forwarding` menu inside the router control panel and set the above rule.